# Detecting modified files during qmake

Tags: c++, qt, build, makefile, qmake

How does `qt` detect if the build is necessary or not, *e.g.* if a source file or in my case a resource file `(.qrc)` was modified after the last build? Is there a flag for each file?
What I exactly want to do is, to send a system command for resource compilation by adding this to the `.pro` file:

```
system(rcc -binary -no-compress resource.qrc -o resource.rcc)
```

And I want to do it only if the `resource.qrc` file modified after the last qmake. Is that possible and how?

Final version should be:

```
if(RESOURCE_MODIFIED) {
   COMPILE RESOURCE
}
```

Comment: Qt and qmake plays no role in this. The build system does. Typically, qmake is used to generate a makefile. The makefile lists the targets and their dependencies. What you need to do is to add a new *target* to your project file, not a system call.

Comment: Could you please give a code example for adding the new target? I think all of the required information is in the system call under my original question.

Comment: I think you need to look into qmake documentation. For what it's worth, is *is* documented :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered in another [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847243/adding-custom-target-in-qmake), the complete correct answer is the following code:

```
mytarget.target = resource.rcc
mytarget.commands = rcc -binary -no-compress resource.qrc -o resource.rcc
mytarget.depends = resource.qrc

QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += mytarget
PRE_TARGETDEPS += resource.rcc
```

This way the custom target will only be rebuilt, if the `.qrc` file is modified and `make` is automatically executed when the application is being compiled.

Answer (score 1):

QMake creates GNU Makefiles (assuming you're using Qt Creator or QMake directly in it's default mode) and the generated Makefile will have a list of targets that will be created, their dependencies and the rules to create the targets. When you build, Make checks to see if any of the dependencies have a file timestamp newer than the target's file timestamp and will run the rules to recreate the target.

Kuba already mentioned it in the comments- you're probably looking to [add a custom target](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-custom-targets).

```
mytarget.target = resource.rcc
mytarget.commands = rcc -binary -no-compress resource.qrc -o resource.rcc
mytarget.depends = resource.qrc

QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += mytarget
```

Comment: In the link you provided, it is about  when the .cpp files are generated. However, in my case I don't have any .cpp files at all. I only have the .qrc and the .rcc files.

Comment: @OnurA, sorry, I misread. Kuba has basically answered it in the comments. I've updated with a link to that section and an example that should hopefully give an idea of where to go.

Comment: it does not work when I run qmake or build the project. However when I run "make resource.rcc" in the build directory, it builds the file.. Why is that? How can I make target automatically?