# Adding custom target in qmake

Tags: qt, makefile, target, qmake

I want to build my resources with qmake as follows  [Qt 5.5]:

```
imageTarget.target = images.rcc
imageTarget.depends = $$PWD/images.qrc
imageTarget.commands = rcc -binary -no-compress $$PWD/images.qrc -o $$OUT_PWD/images.rcc
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += imageTarget
```

When I run `qmake` for my `.pro` file, it generates the make rule for target `images.rcc` target as expected:

```
images.rcc: /path/to/images.qrc
rcc -binary -no-compress /path/to/images.qrc -o /output/path/to/images.rcc
```

So far so good.

However, what I would expect is that running `qmake` would also generate the output file `images.rcc` and it does not.

But when I go into the makefile directory and type in the command "`make images.rcc`", then the `images.rcc` is generated. Am I missing a point? How can I make target in the qmake step without the need of extra make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += imageTarget
```

you just define a new target - but it is not automatically built when running `make`.

Try to add

```
PRE_TARGETDEPS += images.rcc
```

This should automatically build a new `images.rcc` when running `make` if `images.qrc` has changed.

Comment: I can't get this to work on builds with iOS targets?

Comment: the comment about it not working for iOS appears consistent with the docs. docs: "Some backends, such as the generators for Visual Studio and Xcode project files, do not support this variable" https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#pre-targetdeps