# How to add cmake library to qmake project

Tags: c++, qt

I want to add a cmake library into an existing qmake project. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I've only a little qmake experience, but maybe adding a custom target might work (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847243/adding-custom-target-in-qmake)).

Comment: In the CMake documentation, they have a few examples for Qt4 and 5. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-qt.7.html